# Installing specific version of hadoop-client on Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have installed a CDH5(cdh5.15.1 version) cluster on ubuntu nodes and I want to install hadoop-client on one ubuntu host (which is not managed by cloudera).
I added cloudera repo on my ubuntu host but when I run apt-get install hadoop-client , by default it install version 5.16. However I want to install version 5.15.1 version for hadoop-client( which is available in repo).
The problem is I am not able to figure out which version number should I give . The deb package name for hadoop client cdh5.15.1 is:

hadoop-client_2.6.0+cdh5.15.1+2822-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.15.1_all.deb

I have to run apt-get install hadoop-client=< version number > so that it picks up and install the specific version.

Please help me to figure out the exact version number.
Thanks in adv. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `apt-cache policy hadoop-client` to see versions available from your package CDH

EDIT :

use `apt-cache madison hadoop-client`   instead to see all versions available in your packages.

You can also use `apt list -a hadoop-client` which has the same purprose

Comment: Hi Quentin Thanks for quick reply :) But I have tried that already and it just gives the latest package available in candidate .Something like this hadoop-client:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.0+cdh5.16.0+2847-1.cdh5.16.0.p0.18~xenial-cdh5.16.0
  Version table:
     2.6.0+cdh5.16.0+2847-1.cdh5.16.0.p0.18~xenial-cdh5.16.0 500
        500 http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh xenial-cdh5/contrib amd64 Packages

Comment: However I want to install  hadoop-client_2.6.0+cdh5.15.1+2822-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.15.1_all.deb. I have tried something like this : apt-get install hadoop-client=2.6.0+cdh5.15.1+2822-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.15.1 but  i get an error E: Version '2.6.0+cdh5.15.1+2822-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4~xenial-cdh5.15.1' for 'hadoop-client' was not found

Comment: i tought you want the last version sorry : use `apt-cache madison hadoop-client` instead